# json_serialize(...) is returning null even when the input is not null

Tags: sql, json, database, oracle

I have a query like this:

```
select json_serialize(data) 
from mytable
```

Where data is a column that contains JSON but I get a `null` returned from `json_serialize`.  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `json_serialize` returns `VARCHAR2(4000)`.

See:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/oracle-sql-function-json_serialize.html

When the JSON text that would be returned exceeds 4000 bytes, it is considered an error condition.  However, the default error behavior for JSON_SERIALIZE is NULL ON ERROR.

Try adding `RETURNING CLOB`:

```
select json_serialize(data returning clob) 
from mytable
```